# How to equalize results in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working in jupyter with python in order to clean a set of data that I have retrieved from an analysis software and I would like to have an equal number of samples that pass and fail. Basically  my dataframe in pandas looks like this:

```
grade   section area_steel  Nx  Myy utilisation Accceptable

0   C16/20  STD R 700 350   4534    -310000 240000  0.313   0

1   C90/105 STD R 400 600   4248    -490000 270000  0.618   0

3   C35/45  STD R 550 400   1282    580000  810000  7.049   1

4   C12/15  STD R 350 750   2386    960000  610000  5.180   1
```

However the results which are not acceptable (1) are double the results which are acceptable.

no_pass =  8589 no_fail =  16999
ratio = 1.979159389917336

I would like a new dataframe with the same ratio of pass and fails

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
import random
new_data = data[data.Accceptable <= random.random()*1/ratio]
```

It would seem that only one random value is computed and all the rows checked against that, while I would like one value per row.

Any suggestion?

Comment: No. of column don't match number of elements in an observation, can you make a check vink and edit it?

Answer (score 0):

You can sample the data after grouping it on column Accceptable,

```
data.groupby('Accceptable').sample(lambda x: x.sample(frac = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
#to generate random sample

ratio = 1.979159389917336
no_fail =  16999

pass_to_choose = (data['Accceptable'] == 0)
#we want to choose all rows with Acceptable == 0

fail_to_choose = np.random.uniform(low = 0.0, high = 1.0, size = no_fail) < (1/ratio)
#randomly chosen 16999 bool values with relevant ratio of True and False

new_data = data[pass_to_choose]
#select all rows with Acceptable == 0

new_data = new_data.append(data[~pass_to_choose][fail_to_choose]).reset_index()
#add sampled rows with Acceptable == 1
```